# MICROSOFT EXCEL QUERY 2

Tags: microsoft-excel

THE SUM IS UNKNOWN Here "########" but when you total it will have the same value 160,444.76 what should I do to show the value of "########"?

[image]

Comment: Double click the cell right border.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anytime you see a cell with all #s, it just means that the size of the data is too wide for the current column width to display. Just expand the column and you'll see your sum.

NOTE: this applies only to numbers and date/time data.

Comment: @Akina don't be afraid to do that yourself. Is perfectly acceptable, actually encouraged, to edit other's posts in order to improve them, so long as you do not change the poster's original intent.